# Firestore Group Collection Query to return only last document in each SubCollection

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I'm building a 1-1 chat system in flutter which stores the chat data in a firestore subcollection for each pair of chatters. I would like to be able to show a list where the user can see  his chat buddies and their latest messages (a la Whatsapp). I thought I could do something like:

```js
Firestore.instance.collectionGroup('Chats').where('idFrom', isEqualTo: uid)
  .limit(1)
  .orderBy("timestamp", descending: true)
  .snapshots()
```

But this just returns the very last message sent by the user. Could someone please tell me if this is doable at all, or maybe point out an alternative way of achieving what I'm trying to do? Right now the only other alternative I see is to remove the limit and then filter out the last messages client side, but that doesn't seem like a smart thing to do, cause the amount of messages in each subcollection can get very large.

Comment: i think you have to remove limit from your firebase query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're trying to do isn't possible with a single query.  A collection group query considers all documents in all collections of the same name.  It can't make special considerations for each different subcollection.

You will either have to query each subcollection individually, or duplicate the lastest message in a different subcollection that only ever contains just that one message.

Comment: Boy this sucks. Ih it weren't for the real time stuff I'd say goodbye to firestore and go back to good ole SQL Server, for I still have to come across a data querying requirement that can't be handled by SQL Server (or any RDBMS for that matter).

Comment: Data structuring in NoSQL type databases is very different than SQL.  Data duplication and denormalization are very common techniques that help your system scale up massively without maintenance, which SQL databases do not do.  You basically have to choose if you want to solve the problems that come with scaling SQL, or solve problems structuring NoSQL data.  But if you simply don't need to scale very much, SQL might be a better fit for you.

Comment: Anyway, I dreamed up the following solution: add a flag to each new message "latest":true, so I can include this flag in my query. New messages will have to be added in a batch: first update all groupcollections for the given chat pair and set latest to false, then do a create with latest = true. You think that could work?

Comment: That's not going to work well if there are many concurrent additions to the collection that could clobber each other's changes to the `latest` flag.  You won't be able to perform an atomic update (a transaction) that safely identifies the latest message, updates, and adds a new message.

Comment: Even if the only possible additions could only come from either one of the chatters in the pair? I mean it's not like in a group chat where tens or hundreds could be adding at the same time. Your suggestion of duplicating the last message to a different collection seems to make sense, but I  would have to keep deleting previous messages, for a given pair, in this collection when each new message arrives. Could I be doing something like a Transaction where I first delete everything in the collection pertaining to the current pair, then add the duplicated message?

Comment: You don't have to delete the duplicated latest message, just update the existing document when it needs to change.  You can do that in a transaction at the same time that you add a new message.

Comment: You mean like set a flag: latest = false? but wouldn't that have the same concurrency problems of my other solution? And also this would heap up tons of duplicated messages(documents) in this collection which have no use any longer?

Comment: No, don't use a flag at all.  My original suggestion is to duplicate the latest message in a document in another collection.  That can be updated atomically along with the addition of each new message in the main collection.

Comment: Ok, finally got it, I just update the doc in the other collection with the content of the new message. Thank you.